# Was ist die korrekte Anrede in E-Mails an Personen, die man nicht persönlich kennt?

Tags: salutation

Was ist die korrekte Anrede in E-Mails an Personen, die man nicht persönlich kennt?

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren

oder

> Sehr geehrte Frau / Herr ...

Beides klingt sehr formell,

> Hallo

oder

> Guten Tag

dagegen zu salopp.

Gibt es Stilvorlagen im Deutschen für E-Mail-Anreden?

Comment: Also see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25/in-what-context-do-we-write-guten-tag-rather-than-sehr-geehrte-damen-und-herre

Comment: Die Behauptung, dass für E-Mails die gleichen formalen Rahmenbedingungen gelten wie für Briefe, möchte ich anzweifeln. Wo steht das? Wer legt das fest? Das Kernproblem bei E-Mail-Kommunikation liegt ja gerade in dem Umstand, dass E-Mails konzeptionell eher mündlich, aber medial schriftlich realisiert und aufgrund der Asynchronität „quasi-dialogisch“ sind, wodurch definitiv die Frage aufkommt, ob das formale Instrumentarium von herkömmlichen Briefen auf E-Mails unverändert übertragen werden kann.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wenn der Name des Ansprechpartners bekannt ist, dann

> Sehr geehrter Herr Meier

oder

> Sehr geehrte Frau Meier

Ist der Name nicht bekannt, dann

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren

So formell das auch klingen mag, aber es ist die "normale", höfliche Anredeform für Schriftverkehr.

> Liebes Finanzamt

wurde schon vor Jahren von der Liste der gültigen Varianten gestrichen :-))

Comment: Und wann der Name bekannt is aber Geschlecht nicht? Ist es dan Sehr geehrte(r) Herr/Frau Meier (Ich bin Niederländisch)

Comment: Hmm, das wird nicht so oft vorkommen. In dem Fall rate ich auch zu `Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren`.

Answer (score 12):

Kommt, wie schon gesagt, drauf an.

Geschäftlich **auf jeden Fall** die erste oder zweite Variante benutzen. Nur so ist man definitiv auf der sicheren Seite.

Für private Angelegenheiten muss man es der Situation anpassen.

Eine E-Mail an den neuen Vermieter würde ich ebenfalls mit der, zwar sehr formalen aber dennoch sichereren, zweiten Variante ansprechen.

Das abendliche Sportprogramm im neuen Verein ist dagegen mit Hallo/Guten Tag besser bedient.

Bei all diesen Anreden sollte man stets im Hinterkopf behalten, wie man zu der angesprochenen Person steht und die Anrede dementsprechend anpassen.

Als Faustregel:

> **Geschäftlich**: Sehr geehrter Herr/Frau/Damen und Herren
>
> **Privat, aber nicht freundschaftlich**: Guten Tag (Abend und Morgen geht auch, ist aber wieder etwas informeller, da man ja nicht weiß, wann derjenige die E-Mail lesen wird)
>
> **Privat, freundschaftlich**: Hallo, Hi, Hey

Comment: Interessant. In meiner Firma und allen Firmen, mit denen wir zu tun haben (Kunden/Zulieferer/Entwicklungspartner) hat sich die Anrede "Hallo Herr X" eingebürgert und wird - bis auf wenige Ausnahmen - auch genutzt, sofern es sich nicht um eine erstmalige Kontaktaufnahme handelt. In der Regel beziehen die einzelnen Firmen aber die Leute durch Vorstellung ein, so dass diese ebenfalls von Anfang an die eigentlich informellere Anrede verwenden. Dabei bleibt es natürlich in der Regel trotzdem beim Sie.

Comment: Ich denke das liegt auch sehr an der Identität der Firma an sich. Bei uns ist einfach alles sehr kollegial und familiär. Sehr flache Hierarchien etc. Die einzigen die gesiezt werden sind die Vorstandsmitglieder. Unterhalb duzt sich eigentlich jeder, auch wenn man sich kaum kennt. Aber wie gesagt: Das ist nur ein Beispiel :)

Comment: Ich vergaß zu erwähnen, dass wir uns innerhalb der Firma auch duzen und die Anrede daher (Schleswig-Holstein :P) natürlich "Moin <Vorname>" ist, einschließlich Geschäftsleitung :) Das "Hallo Herr X" gilt für Emails zu anderen Firmen. Wobei ich im Supermarkt das "Du, Frau Meier" auch ulkig finde ;)

Answer (score 9):

Emails folgen eigentlich denselben Regeln wie Briefe.

Allerdings klingt "Sehr geehrte..." meist tatsächlich zu formell. Ich nutze es daher nur für offizielle Emails, z.B. wenn ich meine Bank oder Versicherung anschreibe, oder einen Professor von der Uni.

"Guten Tag" halte ich für einen guten Kompromiss. Das nutze ich z.B. wenn ich einem ("erwachsenen") Onlineshop-Betreiber schreibe oder mich um Supportanfragen bemühe.

"Hallo" würde ich nur für sehr jugendlich ausgerichtete Empfänger (vgl. z.B. die Website der Firma/Person) benutzen. Z.B. "Hallo EMP-Team, ..."

Comment: Die Konversation mit Professoren wird für mich dann "interessant", wenn ich nur kurze Nachrichten sende: "Sehr geehrter Prof. X, der Termin am Y geht in Ordnung. ..." ist zwar sperrig, aber man möchte einem Prüfer (und bei mir auch Chef) nicht auf die Füße treten.

Bin ich irgendwo Kunde, dann halte ich kurze Nachrichten auch kompakt und schreibe "Hallo..". Ich investiere dann lieber ein wenig Zeit in eine verständliche, strukturierte Nachricht: Ich denke dass ist den Supportern lieber.

Comment: +1 für Guten Tag als Kompromiß aus Förmlichkeit und Läßigkeit

Answer (score 4):

Für E-Mails gilt generell das Gleiche wie für jeden anderen Schriftverkehr. Das gilt auch für Anreden.

In meiner Erfahrung beginnt man oft mit der sehr formalen Anrede (Sehr geehrte/r …) und lockert diese eventuell auf, wenn man häufig korrespondiert (Hallo Herr/Frau …). Das "Recht" dazu hat der Ältere/höher Gestellte (z. B. Chef, Professor etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Wo ist eigentlich die im Deutschen und Englischen gebräuchliche Anrede "Lieber/Liebe" geblieben. Im Deutschen kann man sie für alle Menschen nehmen, die man kennt, im Englischen heißt es bei Fremden "Dear Sir". 
Hallo sollte man an ältere Leute (wie mich) nicht schreiben. Es wird in meinem Bekanntenkreis überwiegend als distanzlos und ungebildet empfunden.

Comment: Nun frage ich mich, welches Alter "älter" ist. Mein Bekanntenkreis (fast alle Akademiker > 50) hat keine Probleme mit "Hallo".

Comment: Kommt drauf an von wem die E-Mail kommt. Das distanzlose Duzen von einigen Firmen bzw. Online-Services geht mir mächtig auf den Keks.

Comment: Das Duzen ist Teil des Sprachwandels. Viele jüngere (auch ich) empfinden das *Sie* oft als kalt und unfeundlich. Ich vermute, dass sich das *Sie* aus einigen Bereichen der Sprache nach und nach zurückziehen wird.

Answer (score 0):

> He Du Leute

hätte ich noch anzubieten.

Tatsächlich habe ich eine Bewerbung mit dieser Begrüßungsformel erhalten.

Comment: Und, wurde der Bewerber eingeladen?