# "Sehr geehrter ..." oder "Sehr verehrter ..." für Briefanfang

Tags: usage, letter

> (a) Sehr geehrter Herr Müller, ...
>
> (b) Sehr verehrter Herr Müller, ...

Wann verwendet man (a), und wann (b)? Laut [dieser Website](http://richtiges_gutes_de.deacademic.com/3674/geehrt___verehrt___wert), deren Glaubwürdigkeit ich nicht einschätzen kann:

> In Anreden wird heute im Allgemeinen als Höflichkeitsausdruck *geehrt* verwendet: *Sehr geehrter Herr ... Meine sehr geehrten Damen und Herren!* usw. Demgegenüber sollte *verehrt* nur dann gebraucht werden, wenn man einem Menschen, den man persönlich kennt und schätzt, seine besondere Ehrerbietung ausdrücken will: *Sehr verehrter Herr Professor! Sehr verehrte gnädige Frau!* usw.

Heißt das, wenn ich Herrn Müller persönlich gut kenne, sollte ich (b) verwenden, und sonst (a)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auch wenn *sehr **ver**ehrte/r*... grammatikalisch korrekt ist, würde ich von der Verwendung abraten, da es ziemlich gestelzt klingt. Der einzige Kontext, in dem es angebracht sein könnte, ist wenn man seine Bewunderung (-> Verehrung) ausdrücken will, meist im künstlerischen Umfeld. Das zweite Beispiel der Website ist aus meiner Sicht veraltet.

Die allgemeine Anredeform ist *sehr **ge**ehrte/r*... Wenn man den Angesprochenen gut kennt und vertrauter ist, kann man zu ***liebe/r*** XY übergehen, vergleiche auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/195/was-ist-die-korrekte-anrede-in-e-mails-an-personen-die-man-nicht-pers%C3%B6nlich-ken).

Answer (score 3):

Wie der in der Frage zitierte Text sagt, ist *Sehr geehrte Frau X/ Sehr geehrter Herr Y/ Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren* etc. zurzeit die gebräuchlichste Form der höflichen Anrede. Sie kann am Beginn von Briefen und bei der Begrüßung des Publikums bei Reden verwendet werden.

Die Verwendung solcher Höflichkeitsfloskeln in der gesprochenen Sprache außerhalb solcher förmlichen Umstände ist heute allerdings generell weniger gebräuchlich als vor einigen Jahrzehnten.

*Verehrt* ist in diesem Zusammenhang noch stärker als *geehrt* und wird selten beiläufig verwendet – es wird meist bewusst eingesetzt und drückt echte Bewunderung für die andere Person aus (je nach Situation ist natürlich wie immer Ironie etc. möglich). In der direkten Anrede könnte es heute übertrieben schmeichlerisch klingen und daher das Gegenteil des Gewünschten erreichen.

Answer (score 3):

Laut *Duden – Briefe gut und richtig schreiben!* (2006) und *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* (2012) sollte man die Anrede „Sehr verehrte[r]“ nur verwenden, wenn man den Adressaten persönlich kennt und ihm gegenüber besonders ehrerbietig sein möchte.

Als Anreden in Schreiben an eine Einzelperson sind das neutrale „Sehr geehrte[r]“ und das vertrauliche „Liebe[r]“ am gebräuchlichsten.