# Geschlechtsneutrale Anrede bei unbekannten Empfängern

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, salutation

Wie lautet heutzutage die korrekte geschlechtsneutrale Anrede an unbekannte Personen / Gruppenemailadressen?

Eine ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/195/was-ist-die-korrekte-anrede-in-e-mails-an-personen-die-man-nicht-pers%C3%B6nlich-ken) wurde bereits vor 12 Jahren gefragt, aber in den letzten Jahren hat sich Deutsch vermehrt Richtung geschlechtsneutralen Anreden entwickelt, von daher wirkt die dort gegebene Antwort

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren

veraltet. Die in der Frage genannten Alternativen

> Guten Tag

und

> Hallo

wirken weiterhin informell, sind aber möglicherweise die besten modernen Alternativen oder gibt es hier andere eine Empfehlung?