# Wie sollte ich eine Lehrerin, die mich siezt, in einer E-Mail grüßen und verabschieden?

Tags: style, salutation, formality, valediction

Meine Deutschlehrerin an der Universität siezt mich, aber kennt meinen Vornamen. Ich möchte ihr eine E-Mail schreiben. Sie hat mir noch nie geschrieben. Welche Begrüßung und welche Verabschiedung passen in dieser Situation?

Answer (score 8):

In formalem Kontext passt immer:

> Sehr geehrte Frau {Nachname}
>
> ...
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>
> {Vorname} {Nachname}

Immer öfter wird auch folgendes verwendet:

> Guten Tag,
>
> ...
>
> Grüße
>
> {Vorname} {Nachname}

Es hängt von der Formailität ab. Ich denke, dass bei einer Lehrerin durchaus auch die untere Form in einer E-Mail angemessen ist.

Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25/in-what-context-do-we-write-guten-tag-rather-than-sehr-geehrte-damen-und-herre).

Comment: Beim 2. Beispiel geht durchaus auch "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" oder "Viele Grüße", niemals aber "Liebe Grüße". Aber warum hast du nach Guten Tag den Namen weggelassen?

Answer (score 6):

Für E-Mail-Korrespondenz gibt es keine allgemein gültigen Regeln. Mit einer Standardanrede wie in einer schriftlichen Korrespondenz auf Papier macht man sicher nichts falsch, üblicherweise kann man aber für E-Mails durchaus einen lockereren Ton anwenden.

Bei völlig fremden Personen und in einem formellen Anschreiben empfiehlt sich nach wie vor die Standardanrede und Schlussformel:

> Sehr geehrte Frau Müller, [Guten Tag Frau Müller,]
>
> [Anschreiben]
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>
> Hans Glück

Sobald man mehrfachen oder persönlichen Kontakt mit einer Person hatte, darf man getrost auch

> Liebe Frau Müller,
>
> [Anschreiben]
>
> Mit herzlichen Grüßen,
>
> Ihr Hans Glück

oder (gleichwertig und austauschbar)

> Hallo Frau Müller,
>
> [Anschreiben]
>
> Ihr
>
> Hans Glück

benutzen, ohne Anstoß zu erregen.

Dies gilt umso mehr, wenn der Kontakt bereits so gut ist, dass man sich im angelsächsischen Sprachraum bereits mit Vornamen anreden würde. Dann wäre die erstgenannte Standardanrede unangebracht, auch wenn man sich noch [siezt](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/77/23).

Comment: Vielleicht auch den akademischen Titel verwenden; manche Menschen legen Wert darauf.

Comment: @splattne: Titel anstatt "Frau", oder beide ("Frau Prof.")?

Comment: @Tim_N beide: "Frau Prof. ..."

Comment: @Tim N: es geht auch "Liebe Frau Professor... und Ihr..."!

Comment: "Liebe Frau Professor" - also davon würde ich erstmal abraten. In der ersten Email würde ich unbedingt auf eine von neos Varianten zurückgreifen - wenn sie dann mit "Hallo Tim, danke für Ihre Nachfrage. Viele Grüße, x" antwortet, kann man immernoch den Tonfall wechseln.

Comment: Ich muss ladybug zustimmen. "Liebe Frau Professorin" ist a) anzüglich oder b) sarkastisch zu verstehen. Der typische Zyklus in der Geschäftswelt ist: Erstmal `Sehr geehrte`, später dann `Hallo`. Als Ende nimmt man stets `Sehr geehrte`, da wechselt garnichts später

Comment: @nixda: das hängt wohl sehr vom Umfeld und evtl. auch der angeschriebenen Person ab. In meinem (akademischen) Umfeld ist "Liebe(r)... <Titel> <Nachnamen>" mehr die Regel als die Ausnahme, sobald man sich kennt. Man liest auch "Sehr geehrte, liebe Frau..." (dieses Konstrukt finde ich aber eher eigenartig).

Comment: Hach, copy&paste Fehler. Das soll natürlich "Als Ende nimmt man stets *Mit freundlichen Grüßen*" heißen. --- Ich habe jeden Tag regen Email Verkehr mit diversen Kunden und "Liebe Frau XYZ" ist mir tatsächlich noch nie unter die Augen gekommen. Aber es mag wohl sein, dass es im akademischen Umfeld anders ist

Comment: -1 weil mehrfacher Kontakt reicht nicht für "Herzliche Grüße"

Comment: @falkb: das, wie schon oben erwähnt, hängt **extrem** vom Umfeld ab. Es mag vielleicht in einer Geschäftsbeziehung nicht üblich sein, aber mit einer Lehrerin incl Hochullehrerin (das war die Frage!), die man vom Unterricht her kennt, meine ich geht das auf jeden Fall, selbst wenn man sich siezt (es sei denn, man kann sie nicht leiden...).